# convert the categorical data to column names with 3 similar columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I realize similar problems have been posted on StackOverflow, but this one is a bit different. 
Below is the df I currently have:

[image: Current dataframe]

To count for each Director which styles are he/she good at, I wanna transform the dataframe. Converting the categorical data to column names and values are the counts. 
**The problem is** 'Genre1', 'Genre2', 'Genre3' contains repeat values, and I would like to convert all the unique values in this 3 columns into column_names.

**What I have tried**: I sub-sampled them to 3 dataframes, 'Director'-'Genre1', 'Director'-'Genre2', 'Director'-'Genre3'. For each subset, I used 'pivot()' to transform and it looks like this:

[image: each subset after pivot]

**However, I have trouble to merge them together**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand category values could repeat across Genre columns, so one possible solution would :

```
In [10]: import pandas as pd                                                                                           

In [11]: import numpy as np                                                                                            

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    ...:     'Director': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
    ...:     'Genre1': ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Horror', 'Animation'], 
    ...:     'Genre2': ['Adventure', 'Mystery', 'Thriller', 'Comedy'] 
    ...: })                                                                                                            

In [13]: unique_genres = list(df['Genre1'].dropna().unique()) + list(df['Genre2'].dropna().unique())                   

In [14]: for v in unique_genres: 
    ...:     df[v] = df[['Genre1', 'Genre2']].apply(lambda x: v in list(x), raw=True, axis=1) 
    ...:                                                                                                               

In [15]: df[['Director'] + unique_genres]                                                                              
Out[15]: 
  Director  Action  Adventure  Horror  Animation  Adventure  Mystery  Thriller  Comedy
0        A    True       True   False      False       True    False     False   False
1        B   False       True   False      False       True     True     False   False
2        C   False      False    True      False      False    False      True   False
3        D   False      False   False       True      False    False     False    True

In [16]:
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code successfully solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard without data, but consider this;

```
df = df.set_index('Director')
df = df.stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
df.columns = ['Director', 'Genre']
```

This will "explode" the data-frame, stacking all the genre and duplicating the directors for each genre;

```
 Director      Genre
James Gunn    Action
James Gunn    Adventure
James Gunn    Sci-Fi
```

Comment: Thank you for replying my question!

Comment: Thanks again, your code help me solved the duplicate problem!